# How come this array has a length of 13?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

im confused as the following array has only 13 elements in it and shows the length as 13,Why so?

```
class ArrayCopyOfDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] copyFrom = {'d', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e','i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd'};

    char[] copyTo = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, 2, 10);

    System.out.println(new String(copyTo));

    System.out.println(copyFrom.length);
}
```

}

It should be showing 12

Comment: `copyFrom.length` is definitely 13.

Comment: The length is the number of elements in the array, not the maximum index (that is always length-1).

Comment: thanks really appriciated

Answer (score 2):

No, `copyFrom` has 13 elements so the length is correctly reported as 13.

But note that these elements are *indexed* using `copyFrom[0]` as the starting element and `copyFrom[12]` as the final one.

Answer (score 1):

For the array length will be 13, subscripts starts from 0 to 12. 
so the total no of element will be 12+1. That's why it is showing length 13.